# Kendo mvc selenium tests rect is undefined?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I'm doin selenium test on kendo grid. When I change value of the dropdown next step is focus this dropdown with

```
action.MoveToElement(el).Click.Perform()
```

I did it several times and everything was ok, but now I don't know what's going on.

[image]

I testes it and every of these elements got the same error *rect is undefined*.
I do this on modal with 2 tabstrips. On first tabstrip it's working but on second I got this... dropdowns are getting by XPath and checkbox by Id (even checkbox got this issue). I searched a lot but can't find solution.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this needs to be chained with Actions. Why are you doing it this way? I would first just do a regular click for each step, not using Actions. At least break the actions into separate steps where each of the four steps has its own `.Perform().`

Comment: When I'm working with kendo I need to focus dropdown or I got null. On another grid I have also 3 dropdown and I did the same, but there is no tabstrip and I don't have errors like this. I tried separate steps but still with no effect (I don't think it is a problem, I got the same code on this second grid and everything is ok)